# External javaScript file connected but certain code not working

Tags: javascript

I have confirmed that an external JS file is connected as it runs:`alert("Connected!")` successfully. The following code works at console but not via external JS file:

Where the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random Quote Generator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="getQuote">Get quote</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Where JS:

```
$("#getQuote").on("click", function() {

    console.log("click success");

    });
```

Comment: When the `$("#getQuote").on("click"....` code is executed the `#getQuote` is not yet generated. You will have to use `$("body").on("click", "#getQuote"....` or wrap all your code in a `$(function(){....})` function.

Comment: @Titus To confirm my understanding... because the JS is run in the header, it resolves before HTML generates the button?

Comment: Yes, that is right. You just need to make sure you access the HTML element only after they've been generated.

Comment: As Titus says, I would wrap you code in a [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) call, and `$(function(){...})` is shorthand for that. It is also good practice to put those particular `script` tags, just before the closing `body` tag in your doc, so that the dom renders first and for speedier page loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your code inside jquery ready  to ensure dom was loaded :
like bellow

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getQuote").on("click", function() {
        console.log("click success");
    });
});
```